# Why with or without const Modifier make efficiency diff 4 times?

Tags: c++, performance

Why with or without const Modifier make efficiency diff 4 times? This code need about 16 second to finish in my PC. But if I make a small change, like declare mod as const int or move the mod declaration in the main body, or change i as int type, the execute time reduced to 4 second. (I compile this code use g++ with default parameters)

[Here](https://www.diffchecker.com/dy736y1s) is the assembly code for this code, the left part is generate with non-const int mod, another with const int mod declaration.

The big efficiency occur only when I declare i as long long and the operator in for loop is '%'. Otherwise the performance only diff about 10%.

```
// const int mod = 1000000009; 
int mod = 1000000009; 

int main(){
    // int mod = 1000000009; 
    int rel = 0;
    for(long long i=1e9; i<2*(1e9); i++){
        rel = i % mod;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: probably because g++ with no optimization flags doesn't bother to check to see if can treat that var as a const

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When loading the value of `mod` from memory into a register, the generated assembly code is different.

For example, this is what you get when using the Visual Studio 2013 compiler for x64 based processor:

**For `int mod = 1000000009`:**

```
mov  eax,dword ptr ds:[xxxxxxxxh]  ;  xxxxxxxxh = &mod
cdq
push edx
push eax
```

**For `const int mod = 1000000009`:**

```
push 0
push 3B9ACA09h  ;  3B9ACA09h = 1000000009
```

Comment: If swap '%' in the above code whit '+', the execute time with or without thus const modifier only diff less about 10%. rel = i % mod; => rel = i + mod; 
So I don't think loading the value is the main problem.

Comment: @yanyu: I compared the assembly code for each case. The only difference was in the part that I have attached in the answer above. Perhaps you get different **differences** when you use `+` instead of `%`. Point being, all you have to do is to check the generated assembly code, and you'll know for sure the reason for the differences in the runtime performance.

Comment: Can you explain it for me. I put the assembly code in this [link](https://www.diffchecker.com/dy736y1s). The left part generate by non-const code, another for const code. Both use g++ **.cpp. My g++ version is (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2

Comment: @yanyu: I can't explain it in a comment. Publish it as a separate question, and I (or someone else) will be able to address it. BTW, when you do that, publish the actual code (source and assembly) and not a link to it, because it usually irritates most users here.

Answer (score 2):

Because when you add const,the compile changes it into the constant value and write it into the assemble codes, but when you do not add const, the value will be loaded into the register, so you must query it every time you have to use it

Answer (score 0):

A `const` variable may or may not take space on stack - that's upto the compiler. But, in most cases, a const-variable's usage will be replaced by its constant value. Consider:

```
const int size = 100;

int* pModify = (int*)&size;
*pModify = 200;

int Array[size];
```

When you use `*pModify` it will render `200`, **but** the size of array would be `100` elements only (ignore compiler extensions of new features that allow variable size arrays). It is just because compiler has replaced `[size]` with `[100]`. When you use `size`, it will mostly be just `100`.

In that loop `%mod` is just getting replaced with `%1000000009`. There is one read-memory (load) instruction *less*, that's why it is performing fast.

But, it must be noted that compilers act smart, very smart, so you cannot guess what optimization technique it might have applied. It might have removed all of loop (since it seems no-op to the compiler).